# django: form.is_valid() always returns false

Tags: django, django-forms

I have created registration form. When I click on submit button, form.is_valid() returns false. And so my data is not saved. Django version: 1.4
Below is my code:

forms.py

```
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user_type'].required = True

    class Meta:
        model=RegisterModel
```

index.html

```
<form action="/registration/" method="POST">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="8" align="center">
    <tr>
         {{form.user_type.errors}}
         <td> User Type:</td>
         <td style="text-align:left !important">{{ form.user_type }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
          {{form.pricing_plan.errors}}
          <td class="align-left" width="85">Pricing Plan:</td>
          <td width="190" style="text-align:left !important">{{ form.pricing_plan }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
          {{form.full_name.errors}}
          <td class="align-left">Full Name:</td>
          <td>{{ form.full_name }}</td>                        
    </tr>
    <div class="submit-reset">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button" class="sub-res-btn"/>&emsp;<input type="Reset" id="button" class="sub-res-btn"/> 
    </div>
</form>
```

views.py

def user_registration(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    print "form is valid or not", form.is_valid()
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/marketing/')
extra_context = {}
extra_context['form'] = RegisterForm()
return render_to_response('index.html', extra_context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Try printing `form.errors` to see what the errors on the form are. What does your `RegisterForm` look like?

Comment: Can you share `RegisterForm` class please?

Answer (score 2):

Do not reset form when you get invalid form and also show `{{form.non_field_errors}}` in the template.

You can update the view code as:

```
def user_registration(request):
    extra_context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        print "form is valid or not", form.is_valid()
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/marketing/')
    else: 
        form = RegisterForm()

    extra_context['form'] = form
    return render_to_response('index.html', extra_context, 
                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```